# TokenizedTextBox WPF extended toolkit explanation

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, tokenize

I'm currently trying to develop Outlook "Send to" field like autocomplete text box with suggestions, tokenized inputs. Currently I'm trying to develop it using TokenizedTextBox of WPF extended toolkit ( which is not officially available in the released) which is available in their source code. [source site](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TokenizedTextBox&referringTitle=Home) Have anyone used this ?

Edited: Can anyone give me an example of how to use TokenizedTextBox, I just can't get the autocomplete list. code below

```
<Grid>
    <xctk:TokenizedTextBox Name="testtokenized" Margin="0,25,0,240"  >

    </xctk:TokenizedTextBox>
</Grid>

testtokenized.ItemsSource = new string[] { "hey", "Bye", "goodmorning", "goodnight", "OrionCity" };
```

Comment: Yes, many people will have used that control.  You haven't asked a specific question, though - what is it that you want help with?

Comment: In tokenizedTextBox I set the Itemssource property to a string[], but when I run the program, It doesn't show the autocomplete list

Comment: Can you post some example code for what you're doing?

Comment: I Added the code to the question , XAML file code and .cs file code

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
<xctk:TokenizedTextBox TabIndex="230" x:Name="testtokenized"/>
<Button x:Name="sendAllEmail" Click="sendAllEmail_Click" TabIndex="20" ToolTip="Open All In Default Email Client" Height="20" Width="20">
<Image Source="..\Common\Images\Send.png" />

</Button></StackPanel>
```

```
Private Shared Sub OpenOutlook(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strCC As String)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(String.Format("mailto:{0}?cc={1}", strTo, strCC)))
End Sub

Public Shared Sub OpenEmailInEmailClient()
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testtokenized.Text, testtokenized.Text)Then
            Return
        End If

        OpenOutlook(strTo, strCC)
End Sub
```